# C# Compare subString by ignoring escape sequences & Special Characters

Tags: c#

```
String str = "Hello!I'm new here and this is my first question."

String str2 = "Hello Im new here."

// here i want to get index by ignoring special characters 
int startIndex = str1.IndexOf(str2);
```

It would be really appreciated if you will help me out. I'm been messing with the code and google for days but all in vain.

Comment: what are you expecting the value of startIndex and what are you getting?

Comment: 1.Remove all characters which you count as "special". 2. Compare strings

Comment: i just want to get the index of substring (str2) which is an int value.

Comment: Why not run a regex replace on string 1 to leave only alphanumeric and spaces. Then compare to string 2. The regex should be something along the lines of `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$`

Comment: I'm actually making a plagiarism checking software and i'm getting the index of substring and then highlight the matching text in RichTextbox control. and i think it will be very difficult for me to remove characters first and then reform it to original text  which will be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're wanting can be achieved through Regex using the pattern

`"\\W+"`

which matches any non word character (anything that isn't [a-zA-Z0-9]).

Using this pattern you can do a temporary replace on both of your strings then do an `IndexOf()`.  Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "Hello!I'm new here and this is my first question.";
        string str2 = "Hello Im new here.";

        string tempStr = Regex.Replace(str, "\\W+", "");
        string tempStr2 = Regex.Replace(str2, "\\W+", "");

        int startIndex = tempStr.IndexOf(tempStr2);
        Console.WriteLine(tempStr);
        Console.WriteLine(tempStr2);
        Console.WriteLine("Index of str2 starts a {0} ", startIndex);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
HelloImnewhereandthisismyfirstquestion
HelloImnewhere
Index of str2 starts a 0
```

See working sample here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/XIpcj0